# Bootstrap 3 col-xs-.. overwrites -sm -md etc.. in ie8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8

I was testing a page in ie8 and it occurred to me that no matter what resolution it always uses col-xs-.. classes to size content, therefore always looks like mobile version of the website, but stretched out. Is there a way to force ie8 to respect col-sm-.. col-md.. col-lg-.. classes?

Comment: It might be an issue with Respond.js Accordng to http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9 Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of Respond.js to enable media query support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue once I was working with my site.
IE8 and below do not support media queries.
Include respond.js in project.
and then all you need to do is to add this meta tag in your page.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,IE=10,IE=EmulateIE10,IE=9,IE=EmulateIE9,IE=8,IE=EmulateIE8,IE=7,IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

hope this would solve your issue